# Using triple int array

Tags: java, arrays, voxel

Okay, so i created an an int array like so `int position = new int[160][250][160]` to represent a possition in a 3D space (`[x][y][z]`) what i want to do is draw a line from one point to another, but am confused about how to get a number from that array?

if i want to draw a line from point `[78][89][30]` to `[34][75][25]` how would i get a specific number from just one of those arrays? or would it be best just to create 3 seperate arrays? (keeping voxels in mind)?

Thanks - Shamus

Comment: where would you store lines ? you need a seperate array or dimension

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to have a class 3DPoint

```
class Point3D{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
}

class Line{
    Point3D pointFrom;
    Point3D pointTo;
}
```

This is how you do things easily in Object Oriented World

Comment: this is idea, which can be elobarated

Comment: @TechExchange: The class name cannot start with number, IIRC.